# How to select one value of a JSON to display on ListView using ArrayAdapter

Tags: android, json, listview, android-listview, android-arrayadapter

Currently my ListView is displaying the following:

Object[id=1, name=Object 1, ...]

Object[id=2, name=Object 2, ...]

Object[id=3, name=Object 3, ...]

```
List<Object> listObject = getObjectListFromJson(jSonObjects);


ArrayAdapter<Object> objectArrayAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<Object>(this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, android.R.id.text1, listObject);
```

I want to display only the "name" value of the JSON like:

Object 1

Object 2

Object 3

Do I need to write a custom adapter or is there a way to get "name" variable using the default one?

Sorry, I'm a beginner on Android development and to stackoverflow. Ask me if you need more information.

Comment: What type of object is this, Json?

Comment: You're a beginner on StackOverflow too! Welcome! Your question makes a bit of sense to me. Perhaps editing it would help others too. Check this out- http://stackoverflow.com/editing-help

Comment: @Rohit5k2 Yes, JSON.

Comment: @Rachcha I was going to put images etc. but I lacked reputation to do those operations :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After

```
List<Object> listObject = getObjectListFromJson(jSonObjects);
```

do

```
List<String> nameList = new ArrayList<String>();

for (int i=0; i<listObject.size(); i++) {
    nameList.add(listObject.get(i).name); // Change ".name" to the appropriate way to get the name of the object. It depends on the object
}
```

and change

```
ArrayAdapter<Object> objectArrayAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<Object>(this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, android.R.id.text1, listObject);
```

to

```
ArrayAdapter<String> objectArrayAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, android.R.id.text1, nameList);
```

Comment: I believe this will work, I've implemented it but haven't tested yet because I'm having a hard time with the emulator. I've downloaded Intel HAXM but it still takes a long time to load.

Comment: no problem. take your time. Do remember to get the name property properly as you said its a Json object

Comment: Yeah, I did remember. It works as I wanted it to be. Now I need to look on how to pass that data with onClick method to another activity using Intent :)

Answer (score 0):

If you have getObjectListFromJson create some custom object type to hold the ID and the name, then all you need to do is add a toString method on that class to return the name portion. For example:

```
class MyObject {
    long id;
    String name;
    public String toString() { return name; }
}

List<MyObject> listObject = getObjectListFromJson(jSonObjects);


ArrayAdapter<MyObject> objectArrayAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<Object>(this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, android.R.id.text1, listObject);
```